# What data type can you store time in?

Tags: solidity

Let's say I want to create an escrow smart contract that has an added time delay. I want to store the time of the transaction initiation in a struct. What data type would I use? This would be calling the `block.timestamp` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I was being stupid.

I found this in the documentation.

`block.timestamp (uint): current block timestamp as seconds since unix epoch`

The answer is **uint** for anyone struggling with the issue

Comment: Mark, as answered, if possible, please